# Best way to declare form controls for an array of objects in angular

Tags: angular

I am using angular FormGroup to get the values in form inputs by using formControlNames. I can do this if I define each control name. But, my api returns values as follows
`{"_id": {"$oid": "5f90bcc3b662fbf7041dfa14"}, "formAttributes": ["firstName", "lastName"] }`. I did a loop of formAttributes in my HTML using `*ngFor` as follows:

```html
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(profileForm)">
    <label for="formName" class="form-name">
        <input type="text" 
            id="formName" 
            class="form-name-input"
            formControlName="formName">
    </label>
    <label *ngFor="let attribute of formAttributeValues" for="{{attribute}}">
        <input type="checkbox" 
            id="{{attribute}}" 
            formControlName="{{attribute}}">
        {{attribute}}
    </label>

    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" (click)="resetForm()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

. Now, I want to declare formControlNames in my `TS`. I can do that if I do it manually like

```js
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    formName: new FormControl(''),
    firstName: new FormControl(),
    lastName: new FormControl(),
  });
```

But, the fields in formAttributes are dynamic. I cannot do it for every attribute. Is there a way I can make this happen automatically by looping the formcontrolnames.
I tried this, but doesn't work

```js
  createGroup() {
    const group = this.fb.group({});
    this.formAttributeValues.forEach(control => 
      group.addControl(control, this.fb.control('')));
    return group;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. use your `profileForm` instead of creating a group inside of your `createGroup` function.

```
  createGroup() {
    this.formAttributeValues.forEach(control => 
      profileForm.addControl(control, this.fb.control('')));
  }
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jbytjy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Adding static controllers.

```
    profileForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      formName: new formControl('')
    })
```

Comment: This works for the formAttributes array. But, I have an input = "formName" which is not from an array and declared static. How can I add control name to it. Can I add manually? Thanks.

Comment: Use NgModel bindings instead. https://dev.to/jwp/angular-ngmodel-model-and-viewmodel-5m

Comment: @amar add it whenever you initialize your `profileForm`. added to the answere

Comment: happy to be a help :)